# Create an embeddable widget with site content

Tags: nodes

I would like to have a view with an exposed filter that can generate content + code that people can use to embed on their own websites.

http://drupal.org/project/web_widgets seems to be a little buggy, especially when it comes to using views.

Is there an alternate approach I can use?

Thanks.